# change fading edge color in List view android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-theme

I try to change edge color that appears in top/down listview without changing theme.
I want something like that in picture but without using library.
thank you.

https://github.com/AndroidAlliance/EdgeEffectOverride

Comment: I think the whole purpose of that library is to allow changing the edge color, which is not customizable otherwise (to my knowledge). Any reason why you can't use the library?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following attributes in your xml ListView

```
 android:overScrollHeader
 android:overScrollFooter
```

Or you can do it programmatically by:

```
setOverscrollHeader
setOverscrollFooter
```